# How to get the line break /r /n in the input field of pysimpleGUI in python

Tags: python, windows, pysimplegui

I have this code:
and it'll never print what i input end with '/r/n'

i have a scanner handset.it can scan QR code,i need the data when it end his input with the ending signal such as 'CRLF'

but it can read data without ending signal.

for example:
when i input [fffff ends with CRLF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czh8m.png),i wish it can print fffff

and i also try input "fffff\r\n",it can print "fffff".but i need the feature is print the data when scanner scan a QR and ends with the "CRLF"

it's pysimplegui's problem? what can i do?

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time
import datetime

sg.theme('DarkAmber')

layout = [[sg.Text('data：'), sg.Input(key='-IN-', enable_events=True)],
          [sg.Text(size=(40, 1), key='-TIME-')],
          [sg.Button('Exit')]]

window = sg.Window('test input', layout)

text = ''

while True:
    event, values = window.read(0)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    elif event == '-IN-':
        text += values['-IN-']
    elif event == '__TIMEOUT__':
        if text.endswith('\r\n'):
            print(f'{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")} - {text}')
            text = ''
    else:
        print(event)
    window['-TIME-'].update(f'time：{time.time()}')

window.close()
```

Comment: Please add some sample input, the desired output and what you receive instead. Is' might also be helpful to add some debugging prints and post the output. Last but not least: It's `\r\n` with backslashes.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PEP-278 – Universal Newline Support](https://peps.python.org/pep-0278/)

> Any line ending in the input file will be seen as a '\n' in Python, so little other code has to change to handle universal newlines.

I don't have the QR code reader to test how it work.

Try following code to see if it work for you, or not.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time
import datetime

sg.theme('DarkAmber')
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 16))

layout = [
    [sg.Text('data   :'), sg.Input(key='-IN-')],
    [sg.Text('QR Code:'), sg.Text(expand_x=True, key='-CODE-')],
    [sg.Text(expand_x=True, key='-TIME-')],
    [sg.Button('Exit'),
     sg.Button("Return", visible=False, bind_return_key=True)],
]
window = sg.Window('test input', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read(100)

    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break

    elif event == 'Return':
        QR_code = values['-IN-']
        window['-CODE-'].update(QR_code)
        window['-IN-'].update("")

    elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT:
        window['-TIME-'].update(f'time：{time.time()}')

window.close()
```

[image]